# Highlighting a page number in bootstrap pagination

Tags: knockout.js, bootstrap-4

I have implemented bootstrap pagination in my application. Now i have a requirement to highlight few page numbers (will get page numbers dynamically) in red color. Can anyone please point me in a right direction.
Thanks

Comment: Try bootstrap...

Answer (score 0):

You could define an array that contains the pages that should be displayed in red,

```
 self.redPages = ko.observableArray([1, 3]);
```

And, add a `data-bind` for `css` that applies a class `page-item-red` when the current page number belongs that `redPages` array:

```
<li class="page-item" data-bind="css: {'page-item-red' : redPages.indexOf(1) >= 0}">
```

```js
var vm = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.redPages = ko.observableArray([1, 3]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```css
.page-item-red > a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="page-item" data-bind="css: {'page-item-red' : redPages.indexOf(1) >= 0}">
      <a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item" data-bind="css: {'page-item-red' : redPages.indexOf(2) >= 0}">
      <a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item" data-bind="css: {'page-item-red' : redPages.indexOf(3) >= 0}">
      <a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```